# Stored procedure in MySQL with variable on the conditional

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I'm doing a table where I store the last time the users do login/logout. Just one row storing an Id, the action as a bit field and the moment as a DATETIME. My idea is to do a stored procedure to make an insert when the user is new and an update when the user exists. I've done this code:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_LastAction(in id_in int, accion_in bit)
begin
SELECT @CONT:= IdUsuario FROM login WHERE IdUsuario = id_in;
IF NOT @CONT then
INSERT INTO login(IdUsuario, Fecha, Accion)
values (id_in, NOW(), accion_in);
ELSE
UPDATE login SET Fecha = NOW(), Accion = accion_in
WHERE IdUsuario = id_in LIMIT 1;
end IF;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But when I call the procedure it doesn't do anything, just returns the variable as a void field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a UPSERT.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_LastAction`(id_in int, accion_in bit)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `login` (`idusuario`, `fecha`, `accion`) VALUES (id_in, now(), accion_in)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fecha` = now(), `accion` = accion_in;
END //
```

Here's an example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97abc8/6)